# Finding a company that is willing to sponsor relocation

Tags: software-industry, relocation, netherlands

Little context: Non-EU country citizen working in the tech industry as a frontend developer for nearly 2 years now. Self taught / no CS degree. The time spent in industry is not too much, but according to my workplace reviews and conversations with colleagues, I'm considered a pretty decent (mid-level) developer.

My next goal is to move to the Netherlands where I will continue to cultivate my career as a software developer. There are few reasons for this ambition, few of which are: better living standards, the culture and, for me personally, the climate.

However, I haven't had any luck in finding companies that are willing to sponsor the relocation process. For my investigations, I mainly use LinkedIn but I might be missing a ton of companies that might be willing to help a Non-EU citizen to relocate.

Because of that, I have two questions:

- Is there a specific way or a strategy to recognize companies that offer relocation packages? Maybe a website, or LinkedIn filter?
- Is cold emailing the recruiters with resume attached and a question regarding relocation package a good strategy?

I'm looking for ways that will improve my chances of finding a company that is willing to sponsor the relocation process.

Comment: Also take a look to Stack Overflow Jobs (or what its name is now). You can filter companies which wish to sponsor visa and also which pay for relocation (but they probably pay even if they didn't explicitly mention). I moved to The Netherlands and I can tell you that everything is extremely smooth and easy.

Comment: Now I don't live there but I still think it's a good country with great people, also IT market is pretty good in this moment (AFAIK) then IMHO it should be really easy to get what you want (also don't forget the 30% rule)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoRepetti - the stackoverflow jobs board is really helpful tool!

Comment: Just few small tips: get your BSN as soon as possible, check taxes with the online calculator, consider the 30% rule, be aware of the full regulation for the company car (if any), and don't forget that you have to pay for the health insurance. Rents are somehow high but life quality is good. Just out of curiosity...do you really (and I mean really?) like the WEATHER there? Seriously?!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It is a minor thing, but I'd like to give it a try and see how it will affect me. But yeah, living in a country where summer temperatures are just unbearable for me personally, I'd love to try something else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contractual (time limited, not necessarily short term) positions will (actually should) most times grant you reimbursement of travel costs.
Accommodation, if it is anywhere between a few weeks to a few months might or might not be paid.Try to bring it into negotiations.

If they don't pay the accommodation, ask for higher salary.
Ideally ask first for accommodation compensation before you tell them your wage but it works the other way too.
I had both situations and we always came to an agreement that suited me fine.

I don't know that companies put this into linkedin or on their website, unless it is a short term contract.

While it is understandable that you'd like someone to pay your move, it is quite cheeky, isn't it.

If a company asked me to move somewhere, then yes, most would pay. 
In fact, I had that a few times.

However you want to move somewhere and are looking for someone to foot the bill.
Good luck with that.